# How to run Xdebug with Zend Server

Tags: xdebug, zend-server-ce

I'm running Zend Server CE on Windows.  I recently installed Xdebug (so that I could analyse code coverage with PHPUnit), however that stopped Zend from running.  (I couldn't boot the http://localhost:10081/ZendServer/ page.)

I know this is a regular problem - I've read the solution put forward by Zend, http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=553, however this didn't work either.

I read somewhere about running 2 Apache instances, with Zend debugger configured in one, Xdebug in the other, however I don't really want to do this.

What other options are there?  Has anyone managed to resolve this 'with confidence'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted this out.  Upgraded Zend Server to the latest version, then upgraded Xdebug to the latest, and all seems fine.

Comment: It may worked for you, in my case, i needed to change configuration order on php.ini for xdebug to work.

Answer (score 0):

XDebug **2.1.0** does not work with Zend Server CE **5.0.4**.

XDebug **2.1.2** does not work with Zend Server CE **5.1.0**.